# JavaScript Animation Problem (Fat cats dancing)

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why my cats are not moving at all. I am pretty sure they are suppose too. Can someone point me into if they are suppose to and or what I did wrong thanks.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <title>Fat Cat Dancing</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <script type= "text/javscript">
  <![CDATA[
  var cats = new Array(3);
  var fatCat = 0; 
  var direction; 
  var begin; 
 cats[0] = "fatcat0.gif"; 
cats[1] = "fatcat1.gif"; 
cats[2] = "fatcat2.gif";
function dance() { 
    if (fatCat == 0)     
        direction = "right"; 
   else if (fatCat == 2)          
        direction = "left"
  if (direction == "right")     
        ++fatCat;     
    else if (direction == "left")         
        --fatCat;     
        document.animation.src = cats[fatCat];     
} 
function startDancing() {     
if (begin)         
    clearInterval(begin);     
    begin = setInterval("dance()",200); 
}
]]>
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Fat Cat Dancing</h1> 
  <p><img src="fatcat1.gif" name="animation" alt="animation" id="animation"/></p> 
  <form action= ""> 
  <input type="button" name="run" value="Start Dancing" onClick="startDancing();"/>
  <input type="button" name="stop" value="Stop Dancing " onClick="clearInterval(begin);"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cats really don't listen to what people tell them to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('animation').src = cats[fatCat];
```

Your code was assuming that the element would be available by name as a property of "document", but it won't.

Also, as another answer suggests, your "setInterval()" call can be just:

```
begin = setInterval(dance, 200);
```

Comment: I have done this it is not working at all.

Comment: @sha it sure would help out a lot if you could provide some details about what is or is not happening. Are there JavaScript errors?  Do any images load at all?

Comment: the images are not moving when you click on the click button.

Comment: Are there JavaScript errors?  Have you tried debugging it?  That code is not the fanciest thing in the world, but it should work.

Comment: i have ran it through the validations and nothing come up... So i dont know if something is not in there right..

Comment: I'll ask again: are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: No I do not not get any errors

Answer (score 0):

Take out the quotes in the `setInterval("dance()",200);` line and see if it works.

Comment: ... and also take out the () or else it *definitely* won't work :-)